# How does one create an elegant iPhone GUI?

Tags: iphone, xcode, user-interface

This is just one of those things where you feel like your own design is utterly terrible, and that all of the other apps have a beautiful design. This question is just about how you would go about creating a user interface that a user would actually **want** to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work with a graphic designer, and have them mock up what a good working UI should look like, then I come back and tweak the design with what I feel I can realistically make, and hand that back to the designer and see if they think it's ok or needs more changes. I realize that as a programmer I'm too focused on how to make things work then to make them look good, and as such we typically can't create a great UI on our own. Also after mocking up the UI (usually just a few static images on screen or paper) I show it to a few friends (both programmers and non techies) and get their reaction. This step will really show you any deficiencies that your design may have.

Answer (score 1):

Get your hands dirty and use lots of apps. Experience will teach you the interface cues that other developers use to make a seamless and sensible user session. Take notes on how controls transition from one context to another. Observe how controls are organized to make the optimal use of a small screen.

A good review of the iPad noted that the operating system details "fall away" and the user can just use the device through intuition. This is a good ideal to strive for.

User controls should be simple but informative, communicating enough to identify their function, but subtle enough to fall into the background when unused.

Functionality should be organized in a sensible and repeatable fashion. Use the tab and navigation stack design patterns that Apple provides to organize your app's functions.

[Edward Tufte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte) is a good source for reading material on how to communicate ideas simply and clearly.

Of course, you will also want to read Apple's own [iPhone HIG](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH1-SW1) which explains many of the iPhone widgets that users will use and have prior experience with.

Answer (score 0):

I work with a graphic designer. I provide him specifications about what my app does and he provides a PSD with all screens.

But I have to say, that there is a lot of graphic designers, but the quality is not equal.
My preferred is http://www.sockho.com

He designed my both apps :

> **Check-in 360** : http://www.check-in360.com
>
> **Vegas Radio** : http://www.vegasradioapp.com

Thierry